# Dell Poweredge 2850 with (2) attached Powervault 220s will not boot

Tags: ubuntu, dell-poweredge, dell-powervault

I have a Dell Poweredge 2850, which has an additional PERC3 PCI RAID controller.  The controller has two Powervault 220s's connected to it, each with 14 143GB drives. (Also has the built in PERC4 controller with the built in drives attached that will function as the boot drive as a RAID 5).

I can see all of the drives in the RAID configuration utility, and I setup 28 logical drives (each with 1 physical disk) so that the OS will see each drive individually.  Going to setup a ZFS pool in Ubuntu.

When the Powervaults are attached via SCSI cable to the server, it will not boot ubuntu or load the installer.  Initially I was trying to install it, and after choosing install from the boot menu I would get a black screen that never changes. If I unplug the SCSI cables to the Powervaults, it boots to the installer just fine with no special boot options.  It even sees all of the logical drives (all 29 of them) when choosing a drive to install to.

I was able to successfully install Ubuntu server 12.04 with the Powervault SCSI cables unplugged. However, when I plug them back in, I get the same black screen issue after GRUB.

Any idea why it isn't booting with the SCSI devices connected? Thanks!

Comment: The first three hits when I googled "PERC3 ubuntu" indicated that a BIOS update and a flash update to the PERC firmware were required to get ubuntu to recognize drives on a PERC3 card. Have you installed the latest BIOS and firmware revisions from Dell?